# DNS name resolution with traceroute

Tags: domain-name-system, networking, china

i'm using my computer inside China to connect server outside country.
I tried many days a `traceroute` command to **domain.com**, that has ip address `114.157.42.212` and everytime the response is like this:

```
traceroute to domain.com (0.0.27.223), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
```

Everytime i try i get a different Class A address tht begin with `0.0.x.x`, but if i use a VPN (such as OpenVPN) the address is right...

Could you help me to understand why?
Due to without VPN traceroute doesn't work, could happen that chinese DNS (and great firewall system), manipulates DNS name resolution and redirect my computer to a different ip address?

Comment: What if you used `traceroute -n 114.157.42.212`, does it show correct ip addresses then?

Comment: sure, show right ip address :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to manipulate DNS name resolution. It could be done in the Chinese firewall or somewhere else.

As I found, the IP address you provided is in Japan but it’s not blacklisted by the Chinese firewall.

There’re some resources that can help to test a web-site availability from China, like [Blocked in China](http://www.blockedinchina.net). Currently, it shows that the domain name reversed from the provided IP address is accessible from anywhere in China.

Comment: sounds strange the the ip address they use to redirect me.